# Add Team Member in iCloud Dashboard

Tags: ios, database, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

A friend and I are trying to work on the same app using CloudKit together, but I can't figure out how to add him to the dashboard. Under the `Admin` section there is an option for `Team` but when I click on it there is no `+` or anything indicating an option to add him to the dashboard.

***Edit*** I did add my friend as a developer on my developer account but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the team on your apple dev account on the developer site. https://developer.apple.com

Comment: I did that previously as well, no luck.